# Not able to toggle back upvote downvote count

Tags: bug

I was browsing my questions and happened to notice that when we click on upvote count, it shows upvote and downvote counts separately, but there is no way to toggle it back. An image for reference:

[image]

Only way I could toggle back is refreshing whole page. Is it a bug?

Comment: Just checked on StackOverflow. Same issue is there as well. Looks like a bug across SE sites.

Comment: Even I have the same problem since the time the privilege was unlocked

Comment: Similar post on MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236767/let-me-collapse-the-votes-breakdown-after-expanding-it

Comment: Workaround (without refreshing the page): use either of (upvote/downvote) button: this would tootle it back

Comment: @rene Thanks! Yes same question. But still unanswered. :(

Comment: @Pandya Not working!

Comment: A related feature request would be to see the upvote-downvote count when browsing via mobile devices

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the way it 'functions' on at least several other sites; also, it might be nice if it was simply always on, with the net score between the two values. Thank you :)